# How to export field output data and coordinates of a node using Abaqus/Scripting?

Tags: python, scripting, abaqus

With Abaqus, I am trying to export node coordinates and the CSDMG value at each node of my impact model to rebuild it with Python. However, my program does not seem to extract the CSDMG value of the node considered. The value extracted from my Python program are different than those exported from Abaqus/Viewer.
[From Abaqus/Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrDmG.png)
[From Python program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v4Ll.png)

My program:

```
for node in instance.nodes:
    inc.append(i)
    Noeud.append(node.label)
    CoordX.append(node.coordinates[0])
    CoordY.append(node.coordinates[1])
    CoordZ.append(node.coordinates[2])
    CSDMG.append(lastFrame.fieldOutputs['CSDMG General_Contact_Domain'].values[node.label].data)
    i=i+1
```

I suppose the penultimate line reads the CSDMG value at another node than 'node.label'. What do you recommend to improve my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access values of a field output, the attribute `values` acts as a list of `FieldValue` objects. Since the attribute `values` works like a list, the indexes are regular list indexes starting from 0. The indexes are **not** node labels.

Abaqus stores field output results sorted by the labels in ascending order. If you only have a single instance, then the order of field output results matches the order of nodes inside the instance. In that case, you can access the values one by one using a sequential index:

```
for i, node in enumerate(instance.nodes):
    inc.append(i)
    Noeud.append(node.label)
    CoordX.append(node.coordinates[0])
    CoordY.append(node.coordinates[1])
    CoordZ.append(node.coordinates[2])
    CSDMG.append(lastFrame.fieldOutputs['CSDMG General_Contact_Domain'].values[i].data)
```

Please also note that I replaced your manual incrementation of `i` using a built-in function `enumerate`.

If you have multiple instances, then you first have to retrieve a subset of results for that specific instance. After you have the subset of field outputs, you can proceed in the same way as before.

```
field_output = lastFrame.fieldOutputs['CSDMG General_Contact_Domain'].getSubset(region=instance)

for i, node in enumerate(instance.nodes):
    inc.append(i)
    Noeud.append(node.label)
    CoordX.append(node.coordinates[0])
    CoordY.append(node.coordinates[1])
    CoordZ.append(node.coordinates[2])
    CSDMG.append(field_output .values[i].data)
```